# Closing a modal when click on the form submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, modal-dialog, submit

My modal holds a form and I want to close the modal when the user clicks the submit button. The simplified form looks like this:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='{{ module.name }}Modal' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <form ng-submit='submitModule(module)'>
            <div class='modal-body'>
                ...
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Run</button>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the two buttons. The close button uses `data-dismiss='modal'` which works fine. But I can't use that on the submit button, because that "cancels" out the `ng-submit=submitModule()` submission function; the modal will close but the function won't get called.

Would the solution be to close the modal from the `submitModule()` function? But how can I get a hold of the modal from there?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 2):

You can append as many method calls to the (ngSubmit) i.e

*form class="well" (ngSubmit)="addUserModal.hide(); addUser(model); userForm.reset()" #userForm="ngForm"*

Answer (score 1):

You can add one small jQuery code in your HTML file...
Add onclick attribute in button.

```
<div class='modal fade' id='{{ module.name }}Modal' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
<div class='modal-content'>
    <form ng-submit='submitModule(module)'>
        <div class='modal-body'>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' onclick="$('.modal').modal('hide')">Run</button>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular-UI library - Modal: download minified version [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.0.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js):

First include the library in your module:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Then, in your controller, you can close the modal within the form submit function:

```
$scope.submitModule = function(module) {
    dialog.close(result);
    // REST OF YOUR CODE TO HANDLE FORM INPUT
}
```

Comment: I've added the `ui-bootstrap.min.js` in a `<script>` tag before my `app.js`, and I tried to include the library in my controller like this: `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('InputCtrl', function($scope, $http, InputSvc) {...}` but I get this error: `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider`

Comment: Are you using angular router in your app? The error is related to the service $routeProvider which is provided by Angular router. The router is not provided in the main angular library. You are supposed to import another script to use it.

Comment: Yes I am, my `routes.js` maps routes to my controllers and templates.

Comment: Is it possible to place a working demo of your app on Plunker? It would make it easier to resolve the error and implement the modal code.